# "No pending request to flush" in unit test for $asyncValidators using $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I've yet to find an answer on SO, blogs or even Angular issues. I've got other services and controllers that use `$http` and `$resource` and their unit tests use `$httpBackend.when()` to mock the API and `$httpBackend.flush()` to return a response. 
I'm having no luck with this directive, though.

I've created an asynchronous validator, based around the sample code in [AngularJS docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). I have verified that the `$http.get()` is getting called before `$httpBackend.flush()` with `console.log()`. However, I get "No pending request to flush" for `$httpBackend.flush()`. Incidentally, I have also tried `$httpBackend.expectGET()`, and that expectation fails.

**Directive code**

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myServerValidate', function ($q, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$asyncValidators.server = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                    return $http.get('http://myserver/api/System/ValidateField', {
                        params: {
                            field: scope.validationConfig.field,
                            value: '' + (modelValue || viewValue)
                        }
                    }).
                    then(function (successData) {
                        if (angular.isEmpty(successData) || angular.isEmpty(successData.Status)) {
                            return $q.reject();
                        } else if (!successData.Status) {
                            return $q.reject(successData.Message || '');
                        } else if (successData.Status) {
                            return $q.resolve(successData.Message || '');
                        }

                    }, function (rejectionData) {
                        return $q.reject(rejectionData);
                    });
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

**Unit test**

```js
'use strict';

describe('Directive: myServerValidate', function () {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var form,
        scope,
        $httpBackend;

    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $injector, $compile) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        $httpBackend.
        when('GET', /ValidateField/).
        respond(function () {
            if (form.num === '1') {
                return [200, {Status: true, Message: ''}, {}];
            } else if (form.num === '2') {
                return [200, {Status: false, Message: 'Invalid'}, {}];
            } else {
                return [404, {}, {}];
            }
        });

        var element = angular.element('<form name="form">' +
            '<input type="text" name="num" ng-model="model.num" hc-server-validate>' +
            '</form>');
        scope.model = {
            num: null
        };
        scope.validationConfig = {
            field: 'num'
        };
        $compile(element)(scope);
        form = scope.form;
    }));

    it('should validate numeric value against server API', function () {

        form.num.$setViewValue('1');
        scope.$digest();
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(scope.model.num).toEqual('1');
        expect(form.num.$valid).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I expected the `scope.$digest()` to kick off the validation (which it does), which would then call `$http.get()` (which happens), but `$httpBackend` somehow doesn't detect the call, or possibly `$http` doesn't generate the GET request.

Comment: Having a very similar issue and haven't found an answer yet. When running flush I get error that no pending requests are available. I can however see then that the input has been validated. And when I don't run it the input $valid is undefined. Makes no sense :(

Comment: Actually just found my issue. But not sure why this happens. And looking at your code doesn't seem you have the same scenario. In my afterEach statement I ran flush and the verify functions. Removing the flush solved it for me. Not sure why.